# Strange newlines and outputs executing phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I've a strange output when I run phpunit on my project.
My teammates do not have this problem.

I'm on Ubuntu, php 5.5 and i've installed phpunit 4.1 throught composer.

Here is what i get :

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/gb/www/phpunit.xml

................................................
.
.
.............  63 / 473 ( 13%)
............................................................... 126 / 473 ( 26%)
............................................................... 189 / 473 ( 39%)
............................................................... 252 / 473 ( 53%)
.................................................
.............. 315 / 473 ( 66%)
............................................................... 378 / 473 ( 79%)
............................................................... 441 / 473 ( 93%)

.
.
..............................
```

It's not really important but annoying.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It looks like There is echo or  print "\n" somewhere in codes

Comment: Which os use your teammates?

Comment: My teammates use  windows ubuntu or osx.

Comment: There are no echo or print... And why  it works for others ? That so strange...

Comment: I'm always throwing a pen while waiting for the tests to run. If the pen hits the Enter key, that's what happens.

Comment: No, that not my case. New lines are always at the same place.

Comment: Try executing phpunit with the --testdox option. Maybe you can detect where the newlines are generated by looking at the test classes and method names.

Comment: I've found one, it seems that the error_log function create this new line. I don't think that's normal. What do you think about it ?

Comment: @Gilles it could be related with error_log sending data to STDERR but that's a blind guess

Comment: I've tried to change all the option relative to error log in php.ini, no changes... The only difference with others is that I used composer instead of PEAR to install phpunit